# Class toggle backbone , javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a button and icon on top of it. When i click on the button, the class succesfully toggles, however, when i click on the icon inside the button, the class doesn't toggle. 
Here is my html:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne-{{id}}">
    <button id="btnCollapse" class="btn" style="width: 25px;" type="button">
        <i id="accordionIcon-{{id}}" class="right"></i>
    </button>
</a>
```

And the javascript:

```
events: {
  'click #btnCollapse': 'handleClass',
  'click .right': 'handleClass'
},

handleClass: function(event) {
  $(event.target).find('i').toggleClass('right down');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use handler like this:

```
handleClass: function(event) {
  var $target;
  if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'I') {
    $target = $(event.target);
  } else {
    $target = $(event.target).find('i');
  }

  $target.toggleClass('right down');
}
```

Comment: `$(ev.target).closest('.accordion-toggle').find('i')` might be a better choice.

Comment: @muistooshort, also true! Less code, but depending on additional container element. IMHO less dependencies -- is a better code design.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

"This property will typically be equal to the this of the function."
http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/